# ETL using AWS EMR

Tags: pyspark, amazon-emr

I am new to AWS EMR, I have to perform following task using spark on EMR :-

step 1 :- select the xml file from s3

step 2 :- perform transformations on xml data

step 3 :- store the result into Elasticsearch or in any RDBMS

I need procedure of how to do these steps

Answer (score 0):

You can create a transient cluster for this kind of job...
Select step execution and enable terminate cluster on job end.

But if your use case is just reading data from s3 and loading into elastic search I would recommend using AWS Glue as it is serverless and you need not to worry about cluster management and you can pay as you go.

Comment: the xml data I am using is not friendly with Glue..

Comment: xml data I am using is both xml and html, so I cannot specify a particular rowtag for schema in Glue crawler

Comment: I was talking about glue jobs but you can anytime create the EMR transient cluster.